# Benchmarking symmetric and asymmetric cryptography

Tags: cryptography, openssl, benchmarking

In order to integrity protect a byte stream one can conceptually either use symmetric cryptography (e.g. an HMAC with SHA-1) or asymmetric cryptography (e.g. digital signature with RSA).
It is common sense that asymmetric cryptography is much more expensive than using symmetric cryptography. However, I would like to have hard numbers and would like to know whether there exist benchmark suites for existing crypto libraries (e.g. openssl) in order to gain some measurement results for symmetric and asymmetric cryptography algorithms.
The numbers I get from the built-in "openssl speed" app can, unfortunately, not be compared to each other.

Perhaps somebody already implemented a small benchmarking suite for this purpose?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: I don't know a benchmark suite, but the main work for the HMAC is the hashing of the whole message/stream, and this has to be done for the signature, too. (The cost is depending linearly on message/stream size.) In addition, you have the modular exponentiation, which is the costly part of the signature (depending on key size only). So the "how much more does RSA cost than HMAC" will depend on the size of your message.

Comment: Why can't the `openssl speed` numbers be compared to each other? I use them all time.

Comment: I think they can't be compared regarding the different outputs of symmetric and asymmetric operations. For symmetric ones the output is given in bytes per second, e.g.:
`type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes`
`sha1             40851.46k   115649.56k   246194.34k   340589.23k   387393.93k`
But for asymmetric crypto the output is given in signs or verifies per second, e.g.:
`sign    verify    sign/s verify/s`
`rsa  512 bits 0.000120s 0.000011s   8349.2  90190.5`
So I don't even know how many bytes of data are signed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a benchmark is useful here, because the two things you're comparing are built for different use-cases. An HMAC is designed for situations in which you have a shared secret you can use to authenticate the message, whilst signatures are designed for situations in which you don't have a shared secret, but rather want anyone with your public key be able to verify your signature. There are very few situations in which either primitive would be equally appropriate, and when there is, there's likely to be a clear favorite on security, rather than performance grounds.

It's fairly trivial to demonstrate that an HMAC is going to be faster, however: Signing a message requires first hashing it, then computing the signature over the hash, whilst computing an HMAC requries first hashing it, then computing the HMAC (which is merely two additional one-block hash computations). For the same reason, though, for any reasonable assumption as to message length and speed of your cryptographic primitives, the speed difference is going to be negligible, since the largest part of the cost is shared between both operations.

In short, you shouldn't choose the structure of your cryptosystem based on insignificant differences in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, I know about the fundamental differences of both use-cases. But setting aside the challenges of secure key distribution you have still those two methods to integrity-protect a message: an HMAC or a digital signature.
The protocol I use has protocol data units that are approximately 124 bytes long and a router must be able to process thousands of messages at a time. I want to use a cheap HMAC-based integrity protection but I would like to back up the assumption that a digital signature is much more expensive by some measurements that are comparable.

Comment: @taocp It sounds like your application is intrinsically better suited to an HMAC than a digital signature. As I said in the answer, it's pretty trivial to demonstrate the HMAC is going to be cheaper - modular exponentiation is _expensive_.

Answer (score 2):

All digital signature algorithms (RSA, DSA, ECDSA...) begin by hashing the source stream with a hash function; only the hash output is used afterwards. So the asymptotic cost of signing a long stream of data is the same as the asymptotic cost of *hashing* the same stream. HMAC is similar in that respect: first you input in the hash function a small fixed-size header, then the data stream; and you have an extra hash operation at the end which operates on a small fixed-size input. So the asymptotic cost of HMACing a long stream of data is the same as the asymptotic cost of hashing the same stream.

To sum up, for a suitably long data stream, a digital signature and HMAC will have the same CPU cost. Speed difference will not be noticeable (the complex part at the end of a digital signature *is* more expensive than what HMAC does, but a simple PC will still be able to do it in less than a millisecond).

The hash function itself can make a difference, though, at least if you can *obtain* the data with a high bandwidth. On a typical PC, you can hope hashing data at up to about 300 MB/s with SHA-1, but "only" 150 MB/s with SHA-256. On the other hand, a good mechanical harddisk or gigabit ethernet will hardly go beyond 100 MB/s read speed, so SHA-256 would not be the bottleneck here.